# Modifying umask for all users not functioning

Tags: linux, samba, umask

I have modified `/etc/login.defs` and set the umask to 002 but it fails to be changed when I `exit` or `logout` and log back in.  My bashrc file does NOT contain any umask settings.

from **/etc/login.defs**

```
#
# Umask which is used by useradd and newusers for creating
# new home directories.
#
UMASK                   002
```

Any thoughts on why it's not changing?  Despite using Samba, the permissions I'm trying to modify are SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment says: it is used for creating new home directories. The umask to be used normally is somewhere different; probably in `/etc/profiles` or similiar.

Samba, however, is completely independent of the nrmal umask, which only applies if the user is logged in via shell. Instead, you should have a look in `smb.conf`'s

- `create mask`
- `directory mask`
- `directory security mask`
- `force create mode`
- `force directory mode`
- `force directory security mode`
- `force security mode`
- `security mask`

(The manpage of `smb.conf` is very verbose - it has 6632 lines.)

Comment: I've tried modifying it there as well and it had no affect.... we use Samba if that makes a difference

Comment: I think glglgl is on the right track. Are you setting umask anywhere else, for example in ~/.profile? What if you put a umask in your ~/.bashrc, does that work?

Comment: edited for adding samba